# Parkhomov's E-cat reproduction

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, mass-energy

In the beginning of the year, Professor Alexander Parkhomov of Lomonosov Moscow State University claimed to have replicated (as read in e.g. [Wired](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2015-01/30/cold-fusion-energy-advances-2015/viewall)) of the E-cat functioning, albeit with lower effect. Has this silenced most the skeptics, or is the critical debate still in full swing?

Also, is there any other viable hypothesis than LENR that could explain Parkhomov's experiment? Why aren't bigger fish biting, is there still a fear of getting tainted?

Comment: Tommaso Dorigo commented on the 2014 test, called the isotopic measurements "startling" but he expressed deep concern about Rossi being involved in collecting the spent fuel, that the testers may have "overlooked some simple trick" and that "given the extraordinary nature of the claim… this constitutes a major flaw, which totally invalidates any conclusions one might otherwise draw."

Comment: From Wired:

A key aspect of Parkhomov's work is that it is entirely open.

"Parkhomov has openly revealed his reactor design, ingredients used and experimental process, which is not terribly complex, and this allows for further experimentation to take place in the public domain, not under a cloak of secrecy," says Frank Acland of E-Cat World. "If someone now replicates Parkhomov's work, I don't think anyone can rationally deny that Rossi has what he has always claimed."  

Parkhomov's experiment looks like much less than a $million project. I am eagerly awaiting replication.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @KeithMcClary: what about the replication of Jack Cole and hobbyists? If there's even the slightest energy surplus involved, it's bound to be a billion dollar project.

Comment: you asked "Why aren't bigger fish biting?" and Dorigo is a big fish, I am not. It might have referred to a previous experiment?

Comment: My point is, if it's really as cheap and simple as Parkhomov claims, and he has disclosed the complete recipe, then we should be seeing multiple replications real soon now. Ten months and counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a fairly large number of replications of both the Nickel-Hydrogen variant and the original Fleischmann-Pons Palladium-Deuterium electrolytic cell variant. See this for a recent survey: https://www.academia.edu/17964553/Condensed_Matter_Nuclear_Science_October_2015
The results are becoming more mainstreamed (Wired, Forbes, Huffington Post), and thus skepticism should be decreasing.

Both NASA and the Naval Research Lab have acknowledged doing LENR research; the Navy has applied for a US Patent.

As far as theory, the one that is known in the community that has the highest credibility is Widom-Larsen. The theory I favor is based on new physics which correctly applies differential geometry to field equations and, among many other effects, supports harvesting sufficient background field energy to overcome the Coulomb barrier problem.

With trepidation about awakening the trolls, the relevant search is for Myron Evans, and or AIAS.

Comment: Excellent, just for clarification: I've read somewhere that Huffington Post is just a news aggregator?